# maven-eclipse-plugin configuration of directories

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy

maven-eclipse-plugin configuration of directories

Hi,
I was assigned to add Maven support to an existing Eclipse project. Source code is in Groovy.
The idea is that we will have a pom.xml file specifying all project parameters and dependencies and
we will simply run mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate the necessary Eclipse .project and .classpath files.

Important: The project has a certain directory structure that we want to continue using, i.e. we do not want 
to switch to the  Maven structure.

I have tried to solve this with the following entries in the pom file with no success:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.9</version>
       <configuration>  
         <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
         <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>     
    <additionalProjectnatures>    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>                    </additionalProjectnatures>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
....
....
</build>
```

I was expecting this to create the following lines in the .classpath file:


but it does not.
The only relevant entry that I get instead is:

which I guess is some sort of default.

I have tried various proposals both from stackoverflow and from google searches but with no success. 
The only think that gave me some progress is to use the following command line:
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DoutputSirectory=bin 
which indeed gives me the desired path for output in the classpath file. However:
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DsourceSirectory=src
does not work.

I am new to Maven and although I understand that it favors convention over configuration I find it difficult to believe 
that it does not allow any configuration of this kind at all.

Any idea of how I can precisely specify the source and output (bin) directories in the .classpath file generated by the Maven 
eclipse plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you aware that the maven eclipse plugin is not compatible with the latest version of eclipse? the standard way now is to use m2e and forget about eclipse:eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an mvn `eclipse:clean` to begin with before you do `eclipse:eclipse`. Also here is some additional configuration that I found helpful when using groovy with eclipse

```
<configuration>
<additionalProjectnatures>
    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
</additionalProjectnatures>
<!-- Source includes is helpfule to allow groovy files in the java folder, else eclipse might throw a filtering exception -->
<sourceIncludes>
    <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
</sourceIncludes>
```

Comment: @Hilikus: Thanks! I did not know that. 
I am using "Eclipse IDE for Automotive Software Developers" that is based on Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426 so I guess this should be OK for the moment. 

But if the standard from now on is m2e then we should probably heading that direction.

Comment: @Hilikus: Do you know if can configure all eclipse .classpath details using m2e? For example my "original" .classpath (eclipse generated) has the following desirable entries: <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/> <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/> <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/> <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/> <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"/> <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/GenUtils"/>

Comment: Till now however I have not found a way to "persuade" mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate these no matther what I put in my pom file. 
(I am complete newbie to Maven however so probably I am missing essential knowledge).

Comment: This is what you could do. Start with standard java-maven project and then convert it to use your folder structure. At least that way you can triangulate on the issue.